# how to make a python multi-package project install with pip?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

The structure of my project is:

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── mochgir
│   ├── conf
│   │   ├── consts.py
│   │   ├── font
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── Tahoma.ttf
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mochgir.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

project codes are in `mochgir` folder (package).

here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Mochgir',
    version='0.68',
    license='MIT',
    url='https://www.github.com/javadmokhtari/github',
    description='Translate and Analyze docx documents',
    author='name',
    packages=(
        'mochgir',
        'mochgir.conf',
        'mochgir.conf.font'
    ),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    python_requires='>=3.0',
    install_requires=[
        'requests==2.19.1',
        'python-docx==0.8.6',
        'google==2.0.1',
        'reportlab==3.4.0'
    ]
)
```

What I do for packaging it for pip:

```
root@me:~/mm# python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
root@me:~/mm# twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
root@me:~/mm# twine upload dist/*
```

everything is OK until now. but after installation I cannot use my package like this:

```
from mochgir import Translate
from mochgir import Analyze

from conf.consts import *
```

the only thing I can do is:

```
import mochgir
```

and even above code is not OK, it's just a module and does not have any of my code in it.

Comment: What is `Translate` and `Analyze`? These need to present in `__init__.py` in order to imported.

Comment: @a_guest these are classes in mochgir.py file.

Comment: @a_guest I tried to write `from mochgir import *` in init, but still not works.

Comment: You need to put `from .mochgir import Translate, Analyze` in your `__init__.py` file (note the dot `.` before `mochgir`; if you just put `mochgir` it will again look in `__init__.py`).

Comment: @a_guest thank you! and for having `from conf.const import *` what should I write?

Comment: You need to write `from mochgir.conf.consts import ...`. The `conf` sub-package is only available under the `mochgir` namespace.

Comment: @a_guest I just added `from .mochgir import *` and saved it. when I run __init__ directly, it says: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` is it ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174608/discussion-between-a-guest-and-uncle).